# Postbacks fail after upgrade from .NET 3.5 to .NET 4.5.1

Tags: asp.net, webforms, .net-4.5

I've searched for anything similar to what I'm experiencing for a couple of days now with no luck.  I recently upgraded a suite of Web Forms Applications from .NET 3.5 to .NET 4.5.1.  After cleaning up a few referencing issues surrounding NuGet packages, I managed to get everything building and running (locally: IIS8) much easier than I expected.

However, once I uploaded everything to the production server (IIS 7.5, Windows Server 2008 R2), I noticed that post-backs, whether they be triggered from a LinkButton or an autopostback on a DropDownList, only work intermittently.  The first load of the page, everything works fine.  Go to the page again a minute later, click the same button, and the post-back happens but the event handler isn't reached.  The event handlers are attached either via the OnClick or OnChange properties or the 'Handles' Clause in code-behind.

One thing that I find curious is that when the postback happens on a link button click event and the event handler isn't reached, the form is reset.  Does that suggest a ViewState related issue?

Again, everything worked fine when the application was targeting .NET 3.5, and even now that it's targeting 4.5.1 everything works fine when debugging on my local machine (with IIS8), but running in IIS7.5, post-backs are a huge problem.

Any ideas, suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I was expecting to see something in your description about post backs being triggered from inside grids and other server controls, I have experienced this, and have rectified it by setting the ID Mode to Auto ID.

This may not help in your situation though... Worth a shot.

Something else, could you post the contents of your Page_Load? - Are you checking for isPostBack? I guess you are as it has worked in the past...